# C++ OpenCV VideoCapture works differently on different machines

Tags: c++, opencv

I wrote this Windows app, where I use this code:

```
VideoCapture cap(videopath.c_str());
if(!cap.isOpened()){    
    cerr << "Unsupported video format!" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

I supply an example .avi file with this app, and so far it worked on every single machine(win7, winXP, 32bit, 64bit). But suddenly there is one client who claims he's getting "Unsupported video format!" error with the exactly same .avi file which worked on every other machine so far. He's using win7. What do you think is the problem? Is this some codec issue?

Thank you for any advice.
With regards, JP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most probably a problem with installed codecs. You have to make sure that the target machine has the required codecs to decode the avi file you have supplied.

A simple solution would be for your client to install VLC player with the supplied codec pack. Your video contained in the avi is likely to be contained in the pack. Another solution could be to use g-spot and find the exact encoding of your video and bundle a proper filter with your application

Comment: Thanks Eric! I'll try this and let you know what happened.

Comment: OK, so now I am at the company where the machine is, they run Windows 7 Enterprise, gSpot says that codecs are installed, video can be played in VLC, but still getting the same error...do you guys have any ideas please? Could it due to some administrator/user permissions issue or something?

Comment: If it helps, here is the list of files I include with my app: msvcp100.dll, msvcr100.dllm opencv_core244.dll, opencv_highgui244.dll, opencv_imgproc244.dll .I tried to convert the avi file to wmv, it works fine on my machine, but on theirs it's still the same problem...it's starting to drive me crazy...I'll be grateful for any advice..

Comment: are you sure the camera is supported by opencv?